# Arduino double subtraction returning 0 erronously

Tags: c++, arduino, double

I have a function that takes as parameter some double and does a subtraction operation on it.  However I'm getting a result of 0 when one of the parameter is 0 for some reason.

```
int calcPID(double current, double desired, double k){

  double diff;

  diff = desired - current;

  Serial.print("desired = ");
  Serial.print(desired);
  Serial.print(" ,current = ");
  Serial.print(current);
  Serial.print(",diff = ");
  Serial.println(diff);

  int r = (int)diff;
  return r;
}
```

output

```
desired = 250.00 ,current = 1.69,diff = 248.31
desired = 250.00 ,current = 0.00,diff = 0.00
```

When the current is 0.00 the result(diff) is also 0.00 when it should be 250.  Can someone tell me what's going on?

edit:

found out that I was getting a garbage value for current somehow that's not a double (I wrote 2 if conditions if current > 1 and if current <= 1 and neither of them were true).

Comment: There is no explanation for the code shown other than a compiler or library bug (possible but highly unlikely).   A more likely explanation is some other unshown code affecting output (e.g. another function that produces output in a similar form, but prints different results) or some code exhibiting undefined behaviour in a manner that affects values of variables in this function. Try providing a small but COMPLETE sample - in the sense that someone else can compile/link/run to yield the same result. And use C standard I/O, not `Serial`, if possible - more people will have a chance of helping

Comment: I tried to implement your code in the online emulator I always use (123d circuits) and it works. So... It can be a bug.. Please post the complete minimal example that doesn't work for you (for instance write your function and then `void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  calcPID(1.69, 250.0, 0.0);
  calcPID(0.0, 250.0, 0.0);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
}`

Answer (score 1):

This is very strange indeed.

I would suggest to create a second, minimal function like this:

```
int calcPID2(double current, double desired){

    Serial.println(desired - current);

    return(1);
}
```

and then gradually changing it to your original version, and see where it goes wrong (*if* it goes wrong..).

I have had some strange things with the Arduino software too in the past. Maybe you should check if you have the latest version.

You might also want to check if there is no memory or stack problem (i.e. if you have enough free memory left).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something with the floating point calculation. Have a look at this: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Float or google it and you will find pretty good answers :)

Comment: From what I see they are getting some number that is close to the answer which I get but I'm getting a straight up zero which Im stumped on.

Comment: Use float instead of double, maybe that will help.